# How to create a transparent radial gradient with python?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, gradient, radial-gradients

I am trying to create a radial gradient that fades to the clear background. My goal is to create this gradient and paste it as the background to another image.

So far, i have been able to create a circular gradient, but it i not transparent. i found the code below in stackoverflow :

```
imgsize=(650,650)
image = Image.new('RGBA', imgsize)
innerColor = [153,0,0]
for y in range(imgsize[1]):
    for x in range(imgsize[0]):
         distanceToCenter = math.sqrt((x - imgsize[0]/2) ** 2 + (y - imgsize[1]/2) ** 2)
         distanceToCenter = float(distanceToCenter) / (math.sqrt(2) * imgsize[0]/2)
         r = distanceToCenter + innerColor[0] * (1 - distanceToCenter)
         g =  distanceToCenter + innerColor[1] * (1 - distanceToCenter)
         b =  distanceToCenter + innerColor[2] * (1 - distanceToCenter)
         image.putpixel((x, y), (int(r), int(g), int(b)))
```

[this is the image that is produced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbLVY.jpg)
i would like to not have it fade to black, but to clear instead.

thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I would just draw your solid red and calculate a transparency layer with **Numpy** and push it in:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Define width and height of image
W, H = 650, 650

# Create solid red image
im = Image.new(mode='RGB', size=(W,H), color=(153,0,0))

# Create radial alpha/transparency layer. 255 in centre, 0 at edge
Y = np.linspace(-1, 1, H)[None, :]*255
X = np.linspace(-1, 1, W)[:, None]*255
alpha = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
alpha = 255 - np.clip(0,255,alpha)

# Push that radial gradient transparency onto red image and save
im.putalpha(Image.fromarray(alpha.astype(np.uint8)))
im.save('result.png')
```

[image]

**Keywords**: Python, image processing, radial gradient, alpha, transparency.

Comment: Thank You!!! you are the best! Worked perfectly, the image is completely clear. The previous answer allowed me to get transparency, outter edged were opaque and not completely clear. THANKS !

Comment: Mark Setchell, I created another question similar to this. Please check it out, if you think you can help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62456912/how-to-create-a-transparent-gradient-along-the-edge-of-an-image-mask-image-with

Answer (score 3):

It's simple math: white/opaque is 255, so you need *i*-th dimension to be `innerColor[i] + distanceToCenter * (255 - innerColor[i])` and add transparency parameter to pixel tuple `int((1 - distanceToCenter) * 255)`:

```py
imgsize=(650,650)
image = Image.new('RGBA', imgsize)
innerColor = [153,0,0]
for y in range(imgsize[1]):
    for x in range(imgsize[0]):
         distanceToCenter = math.sqrt((x - imgsize[0]/2) ** 2 + (y - imgsize[1]/2) ** 2)
         distanceToCenter = float(distanceToCenter) / (math.sqrt(2) * imgsize[0]/2)
         r =  innerColor[0] + distanceToCenter * (255 - innerColor[0])
         g =  innerColor[1] + distanceToCenter * (255 - innerColor[1])
         b =  innerColor[2] + distanceToCenter * (255 - innerColor[2])
         # Or just 
         # r = innerColor[0]
         # g = innerColor[1]
         # b = innerColor[2]
         # if not blending with white as you get farther away from the center.
         image.putpixel((x, y), (int(r), int(g), int(b), int((1 - distanceToCenter) * 255)))
```

Result is:

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're blending with white as you get farther away from the center.  Why are you doing that?  Just changing the alpha should be enough by itself.

Comment: This worked in getting me the transparency but as Mark said, it blends with white on the edges, giving it an opaque look.