# How to create a transparent gradient along the edge of an image/mask image with python?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, computer-vision, gradient

Basically I want to create of a halo effect for the image that fades to transparent.

I have images of wounds (and their masks), with no background. I want to add a red gradient behind it, that way if I paste it on something it looks like the area surrounded the wound is irritated.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOhYF.png)
and 
[mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQ6jE.jpg)
...

Originally, I was making a radial (circle) gradient and pasted my transparent image on it, but this does not look good for my non circular images.

[image with circle gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWDrt.png)

[same image as above,but pasted on white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDRWx.png) easier to see gradient

...

Now, i think the best idea would be to make the gradient in a shape the goes around the edge of the image to a certain distance and fades. 
something like this ( i did this poorly with paint ... but basically for it to go out a certain distance, from the edge of the object, and fade out)

[paint version of what i would like to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07gYa.jpg)
...

My code for the the circle gradient is posted below, this creates a transparent circle gradient. Once i have this i paste my transparent image on it. I do not know how to change this code so that it creates the gradient the edge of the image.

```
import numpy as np, 
from PIL import Image

W,H=900,900
im = Image.new(mode='RGB', size=(W,H), color=(153,0,0))
Y = np.linspace(-1, 1, H)[None, :]*255
X = np.linspace(-1, 1, W)[:, None]*255
alpha = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2) # equation of a circle 
alpha = 255 - np.clip(0,255,alpha)
```

Please help