# Radial Color Gradient For Polygon in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, gradient, radial-gradients

I'm trying to figure out how to color a Shapely polygon with a radial gradient. I start with some points and buffer them to circles. I used Grad from colorir to create a gradient of colors, but I want each circle to be a darker color at the center and fade to transparent at the edges. I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62045155/how-to-create-a-transparent-radial-gradient-with-python) and am able to generate the image but I don't know how to apply it to my circles.

Here's my code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
from colorir import Grad, PolarGrad

# functions for plotting

def plot_coords(coords, color):
    pts = list(coords)
    x, y = zip(*pts)
    # print(color)
    plt.plot(x,y, color="w", linewidth=.5)
    plt.fill_between(x, y, facecolor=color, alpha = 0.4)


def plot_polys(polys, color):
    for poly, color in zip(polys, color):
        plot_coords(poly.exterior.coords, color)

x = 0
y = 0
h = 1.73205080757

# points

color_points = [
          Point(x, y),
           Point((x + 2), y),
           Point((x - 2), y),
           Point((x + 1), (y + h)),
           Point((x - 1), (y + h)),
           Point((x + 1), (y - h)),
           Point((x - 1), (y - h))]

# buffer to circles
color_circles = []
for point in color_points:
    color_circles.append(point.buffer(2))

# create gradient
p_grad = PolarGrad(["#2b70f3", "#f3ae2b"])
p_grad_colors = p_grad.n_colors(7)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)

ax.set_aspect('equal')

plot_polys(color_circles, p_grad_colors)
plt.show()
```

My output looks like this:

[image]

But I would like each circle to look more like this:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!